# Automate Follow-Up Email Tasks in Salesforce with Toggle Button

Tags: salesforce, crm

I'm working on a Salesforce project where I've set up follow-up email templates for customer communication. Initially, I was manually creating tasks in Salesforce for follow-up emails. However, I now want to streamline the process and make it more efficient.

I'm looking to create an automation solution where I can control the sending of follow-up emails with just one toggle button. When the toggle is "on," the follow-up email should be sent automatically to the customer through Salesforce. When the toggle is "off," I want the option to send the email manually, but with all the necessary details pre-filled.

Could someone please guide me on how to implement this automation within Salesforce? What tools, triggers, or processes should I use to achieve this functionality?